# TypeScript: having trouble typing useReducer with generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am writing a custom hook called `useRequest` where it manages data fetching. The user would need to pass the type for the data that gets resolved in the promise and an optional error type that defaults to the `unknown` type

Here is the implementation.

```
enum Status {
  pending = "pending",
  resolved = "resolved",
  rejected = "rejected"
}

type State<R, E = unknown> = {
  status: Status;
  data: null | R;
  error: null | E;
};

type Action<R, E = unknown> =
  | { type: Status.pending }
  | { type: Status.resolved; data: R }
  | { type: Status.rejected; error: E };

function reducer<R, E>(state: State<R, E>, action: Action<R, E>): State<R, E> {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Status.pending: {
      return { status: Status.pending, data: null, error: null };
    }
    case Status.resolved: {
      return { status: Status.resolved, data: action.data, error: null };
    }
    case Status.rejected: {
      return { status: Status.rejected, data: null, error: action.error };
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error(`unhandled action type`);
    }
  }
}

function useRequest<R, E = unknown>(intialState: State<R, E>) {
  const [state, unsafeDispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, {
    status: Status.pending,
    data: null,
    error: null,
    ...intialState
  });
  // omit implementation details
}
```

However, the `state` is not property typed, its type is `State<unknown, unknown>`

I tried to look for the solution in the existing questions and I found this [Generic type in useReducer for a returned parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55396438/generic-type-in-usereducer-for-a-returned-parameter) however, its approach doesn't seem to be working either. i.e.

```
function createReducer<R, E = unknown>() {
  return function reducer<R, E>(
    state: State<R, E>,
    action: Action<R, E>
  ): State<R, E> {
    switch (action.type) {
      case Status.pending: {
        return { status: Status.pending, data: null, error: null }
      }
      case Status.resolved: {
        return { status: Status.resolved, data: action.data, error: null }
      }
      case Status.rejected: {
        return { status: Status.rejected, data: null, error: action.error }
      }
      default: {
        throw new Error(`unhandled action type`)
      }
    }
  }
}

export default function useRequest<R, E = unknown>(intialState: State<R, E>) {
  const reducer = createReducer<R, E>()
  const [state, unsafeDispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    status: Status.pending,
    data: null,
    error: null,
  })
```

`state`'s type is still `State<unknown, unknown>`

Can anyone help me properly type `useReducer` here? and I also looking for any other feedback / suggestions for the typing here. Thanks.

here is the live demo you can play with https://codesandbox.io/s/usereducer-7vvqz

Answer (score 0):

Your reducer function needs your generic passed to it, so make your reducer return a function

ie.

```js
function reducer<R, E>() {
  return function actualReducer(state: State<R, E>, action: Action<R, E>): State<R, E> {
    ...
}

function useRequest<R, E = unknown>(intialState: State<R, E>) {
  const [state, unsafeDispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer<R>(), {
    ...
  }
}
```

Note that this is calling a function every render, which is likely not to be performant (you could memoize it to counteract this), but it works

EDIT: Just noticed that the second implementation from OP has this suggestion, just leaving this answer here because it worked for me and clearly highlights the difference between the implementations